# Как передать List объектов из одного котроллера в другой?

Tags: java, spring, mvc, spring-mvc

**Здравствуйте!**

Есть контроллер, который формирует список объектов и выводит их в таблицу на странице, и есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую объекты из данного списка должны записываться в базу данных. Но список не должен формироваться заново и страница не должна полностью перегружаться.

Как это можно сделать?

Хотел у кнопки прописать вызов другого контроллера (@ResponceBody), который бы и записывал данные в БД, но не знаю как мне передать уже сформированный список объектов из 1-го в контроллера в тот, что будет делать запись в БД.

Помогите пожалуйста!

Контроллер, формирующий список объектов:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/administration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String administration(Model uiModel,@RequestParam(value = "latitude",required = false) String latitude, @RequestParam(value = "longitude",required = false) String longitude,
                             @RequestParam(value = "post",required = false) String post,
                             @RequestParam(value = "yearStart",defaultValue ="2019") String yearStart, @RequestParam(value = "monthStart",defaultValue ="5") String monthStart,
                             @RequestParam(value = "dayStart",defaultValue ="10") String dayStart, @RequestParam(value = "yearFinish",defaultValue ="2019") String yearFinish,
                             @RequestParam(value = "monthFinish",defaultValue ="5") String monthFinish, @RequestParam(value = "dayFinish",defaultValue ="15") String dayFinish,
                             @RequestParam(value = "hourStep",defaultValue ="6") String hourStep, @RequestParam(value = "aggregate",defaultValue="") String aggregate) {

    List<WeatherDarkSky> listWeatherDarkSky= null;

    try {
            listWeatherDarkSky = weatherDarkSkyService.getWeather(Integer.valueOf(yearStart), Integer.valueOf(monthStart), Integer.valueOf(dayStart), 00,
                    Integer.valueOf(yearFinish), Integer.valueOf(monthFinish), Integer.valueOf(dayFinish), 24, latitude, longitude, Integer.valueOf(hourStep));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    uiModel.addAttribute("listWeatherDarkSky",listWeatherDarkSky);

    return "administration";
}
```

Контроллер, который по идее должен производить запись в БД:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.POST)//Mapping web context, на который будет реагировать метод
public @ResponseBody String download(@RequestParam(value = "aggregate",defaultValue ="something") String objectList) {
    //Запись в БД

    return objectList;
}
```

вот я сформировал ajax-функцию:

```
function createXMLHttp() {
            var Request = false;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                //Gecko-совместимые браузеры, Safari, Konqueror
                Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject)
            {
                //Internet explorer
                try
                {
                    Request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (CatchException)
                {
                    Request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
            }

            if (!Request)
            {
                alert("Невозможно создать XMLHttpRequest");
            }
            return Request;
        }
        function getAjax(url, callback) { // функция Ajax GET

            // создаем Объект
            var oXmlHttp = createXMLHttp();
            var body='aggregate='+encodeURIComponent('value');
            // подготовка, объявление заголовков
            oXmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
            oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
            // описание функции, которая будет вызвана, когда придет ответ от сервера
            oXmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (oXmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                    if (oXmlHttp.status == 200) {
                        callback(oXmlHttp.responseText);
                    } else {
                        callback(oXmlHttp.statusText);
                    }
                }
            }
            oXmlHttp.send(body);
        }
```

Как мне теперь передать через неё данные хранящиеся в table?

```html
<H2>Данные c файла</H2>
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID Поста</th>
            <th>Дата</th>
            <th>Время</th>
            <th>Уровень снега</th>
            <th>Плотность снега</th>
            <th>Промерзание почвы</th>
            <th>Температура воды</th>
            <th>Толщина льда на водоёме</th>
            <th>Уровень воды</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${hydrologyList}" var="hydrology">
            <tr>
                <td>${hydrology.namePost}</td>
                <td>${hydrology.localDate}</td>
                <td>${hydrology.localTime}</td>
                <td>${hydrology.levelSnow}</td>
                <td>${hydrology.hardnessSnow}</td>
                <td>${hydrology.levelFreezingGround}</td>
                <td>${hydrology.temperatureWater}</td>
                <td>${hydrology.heightIceOnWater}</td>
                <td>${hydrology.lewelWater}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Из одного контроллера вызывать методы другого контроллера не нужно никогда, нужно вызывать методы сервиса, которые они используют. А контроллеры уже могут использовать одинаковые методы.

Comment: А как мне передать List объектов в метод сервиса снова не вызывая контроллер, в котором этот  List объектов уже сформирован?

Comment: В вашем случае, вам просто нужно сформировать ajax запрос, который и подразумевает не перезагрузку страницы, после чего получить список данных и добавить из в таблицу.

Comment: @Andrii Torzhkov, вот я сформировал ajax-функцию (добавил в текст вопроса. А как мне теперь сохранить список из таблица и передать его в эту функцию?